# Can't Install Python on Windows 7 (0xc0000005)

Tags: python, windows-7

When I try to download python 3 to my computer it can't run. Because it shows me the classic 0xc0000005 error. So, I've tried every solution that I could find, it still doesn't work. (I've tried installing the newest IE version and disabled all chrome auto update. I've also search my pc with Avast for malwares and found nothing)

Any good solution?
Thanks

Comment: Does your browser crash when you try to download python? Does it say "The application is unable to start correctly (0xc0000005) Click to close the application?"

Comment: Riccardo  No, it doesn't crash

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a default troubleshooting that can help you (because this is a os error):

Try reboot pc.
Then open cmd (run like administrator).
Write sfc /scannow (here u control that your os has no problem).

PS: are u sure that u choose the correct version of python (i mean 32/64 bit)

Comment: I first downloaded the 32-bit by accident and realized it after trying to run Python. Then I deleted it and installed the 64-bit version and it kept showing me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Install any Linux system physical or in a virtual machine. Sorry, may not be your solution but would solve all problems you wrote of :-)

At Windows you could take any portable version of Python.
One good choice would be [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/)
Your error seems to be a permission problem.
[Here](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-how-to-fix-0xc0000005-error/) you have some more informations.

Comment: What does linux have to do with running python on windows?

Comment: Linux contains Python and it is running out of the box. Most devs are using either Mac or Linux so its a valid solution to put in for my opinion.

Comment: There are about as many devs using [windows as there are mac](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology-_-platforms). The OP is using windows and installing a different OS for what could just be "hello world" is not a good solution

Comment: installing any linux on a vm takes about 20minutes and you dont need to drop off Windows. Using a portable python version would be a fast solution on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I am not working on a VM. And that site didn't help me either. But again thanks for your time 